# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC20amplify_auth_cognito16SwiftAuthCognito", in Flutter App

Tags: ios, flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am getting this error while building for iOS

'''Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"*OBJC_CLASS*$__TtC20amplify_auth_cognito16SwiftAuthCognito", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AuthCognito.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'''

I have tried these.
This error seems to be caused by Amplify SDK I am using for AWS.
So I had implemented amplify SDK to a new project where it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is on some of the `XCode` project files, try:

1.Make a backup of your project.

2.Run this command

flutter clean && \ rm ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock && \ rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace && \ flutter run

Comment: I tried this but this didn't work for me